# Issue in converting px to dp for samsang galaxy tab

Tags: android

I am creating android application using java code. we are converting DIP to PX using below code

```
Px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dip, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().metrics);
```

Galaxy Tab 7inch (sdk version 3.2) :
                 density=1.0 width=1024, height=600 and picking the values from values-large folder

Galaxy Tab 7inch (sdk version 2.2) :
                 density=1.5 width=1024, height=600 and picking the values from values-large folder

That’s why in galaxyTab 2.2 value also coming from values-large folder and because of density 1.5 , its multiplying 1.5

thanks
binish

Comment: Your question is not clear as for me. Please clarify where is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

both are large device.

only difference is 7' 3.2 is mdpi and 7' 2.2 is hdpi.

if you didnt provide any folder for corresponding values it will take from default as values-large

if you want to diff you can create one forlder with `values-large-mdpi`

and `values-large-hdpi`

Answer (score -1):

This is a common samsung issue since update to 3.0 and above.

Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for new values